# DateTime parsing results in "Failed to parse time string" error

Tags: php, datetime

Code:

```
<?php 
    $date =new \DateTime($_GET['date'],new \DateTimeZone('Africa/Maputo')); ?>
```

Error:

> vFatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2022-06-14T06:00:00 02:00) at position 20 (0): Double time specification in C:\xampp2\htdocs\fullcalendar\views\user\add.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\fullcalendar\views\user\add.php(3): DateTime->__construct('2022-06-14T06:0...', Object(DateTimeZone)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp2\htdocs\fullcalendar\views\user\add.php on line 3

Comment: <?php $date =new \DateTime($_GET['date'],new \DateTimeZone('Africa/Maputo')); ?>

Comment: `2022-06-14T06:00:00 02:00` isn't quite valid. It's missing the `+` from the timezone, `'2022-06-14T06:00:00+02:00'` because the webserver is changing the plus sign to a space.. This is why using POST is better than GET when passing in strings like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have extra " 02:00" characters in your date from GET-parameter. You just have to use "2022-06-14T06:00:00" instead of "2022-06-14T06:00:00 02:00" and it will work.
2. Remember that `new DateTime` might throw an Exception if date-time format is not valid.

Below are fixed code sample that will work for you in any way. Try to check and play with it: uncomment some lines and see how it goes.

```
<?php

$default = 'now';
$dateParam = $_GET['date'] ?? $default;
//$dateParam = '2022-06-30 00:00:00'; // correct
//$dateParam = '2022-06-14T06:00:00'; // correct (2)
//$dateParam = '2022- 06- 30'; // not correct
//$dateParam = '2022-06-14T06:00:00 02:00'; // not correct (2)

try {
    $dateTime = new \DateTime($dateParam, new \DateTimeZone('Africa/Maputo'));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //$dateTime = new \DateTime($default);
    die('The error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}


var_dump($dateTime);
```